# how to set basic authorization header for GET service in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5

Can I get a sample code to set basic authorization as header along with other headers ( like x-csrf-token : fetch) in eclipse ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with jQuery (which is of course included with UI5) for basic authentication:

```
function ajaxBeforeSend(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + password));
}

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            ajaxBeforeSend(xhr);
        }
}).done(function(data) { /* do something */ }
```

This is what I've used in some developments and it works well. You can set other headers this way as well.
See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_btoa.asp for details on btoa() which base64 encodes the user:pass string.

Your question says: "in eclipse". I don't know what that means as the javascript will work regardless of what editor you use.

Here's the jQuery doco which describes the method used above: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

(Watch out for CORS issues if service is not on the same host as your app. For CORS I find you also need to add xhr.withCredentials = true; inside the above ajaxBeforeSend() function.)